# Convert date records from row to column with mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to convert row data to columns. I tried using my pivot to successfully display the date record in the column but the results are like this:

[image]

How to produce a display like this instead:

[image]

And this is the mysql procedure

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
           CONCAT('IF( ru.TANGGAL=''', 
                    ru.TANGGAL, ''', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '
                    , "'",DATE_FORMAT(ru.TANGGAL, "%d %M %Y"),"'"
                    )  
              ORDER BY ru.TANGGAL)
              INTO @sql
from report_users ru WHERE ru.TANGGAL BETWEEN @p0 and @p1; 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.NAMA_LENGKAP, ', @sql, ' FROM report_users ru join users u on u.id_user=ru.id_users where ru.tanggal between "',@p0,'" and "',@p1,'" ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Enumerate (`ROW_NUMBER()`) the records in each group by `nama_lengkap, datefield` for each `datefield` separately. Add `GROUP BY u.nama_lengkap, rownumber`. Wrap `datefield` into `MAX()`. But I'd recommend to do this on the client side using its report subsystem.

Comment: @Akina I'm still confused how to do it

Comment: Provide [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) with source tables structures, sample data, procedure text, current output, and show desired output in table form.

Comment: @Akina this is a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d247467001a70a7dd10df03d55545b91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, in provided fiddle, your code generates the next query text which is then prepared and executed:

```
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @customer_no = ru.ID_USERS 
                         THEN @row_number + 1
                         ELSE 1
                         END AS num, 
       @customer_no:=ru.ID_USERS id, 
       u.NAMA_LENGKAP, 
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-02', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '02 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-07', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '07 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-10', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '10 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-11', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '11 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-12', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '12 February 2020' 
FROM report_users ru 
join users u on u.id_user=ru.id_users 
where ru.tanggal between "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-12"
```

Let's store this result into temporary table:

```
SET @sql2 := CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ', @sql);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Now we will obtain the result which you need.

We enumerate each record in each separate value column, then group by this number:

```
WITH cte2 AS (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN `02 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `02 February 2020`='', `02 February 2020`)
               WHEN `07 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `07 February 2020`='', `07 February 2020`)
               WHEN `10 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `10 February 2020`='', `10 February 2020`)
               WHEN `11 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `11 February 2020`='', `11 February 2020`)
               WHEN `12 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `12 February 2020`='', `12 February 2020`)
               END rn
FROM temp
)
SELECT id,
       NAMA_LENGKAP,
       MAX(`02 February 2020`),
       MAX(`07 February 2020`),
       MAX(`10 February 2020`),
       MAX(`11 February 2020`),
       MAX(`12 February 2020`)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, NAMA_LENGKAP, rn;
```

The result seems to be one you need.

Now we may exclude intermediate temporary table and convert the query which generates it into CTE:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @customer_no = ru.ID_USERS 
                         THEN @row_number + 1
                         ELSE 1
                         END AS num, 
       @customer_no:=ru.ID_USERS id, 
       u.NAMA_LENGKAP, 
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-02', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '02 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-07', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '07 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-10', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '10 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-11', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '11 February 2020',
       IF( ru.TANGGAL='2020-02-12', concat(if(ru.JENIS=01, "Pagi","Sore"), " ", DATE_FORMAT(ru.CRTIME, "%H:%i")), "") AS '12 February 2020' 
FROM report_users ru 
join users u on u.id_user=ru.id_users 
where ru.tanggal between "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-12" 
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN `02 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `02 February 2020`='', `02 February 2020`)
               WHEN `07 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `07 February 2020`='', `07 February 2020`)
               WHEN `10 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `10 February 2020`='', `10 February 2020`)
               WHEN `11 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `11 February 2020`='', `11 February 2020`)
               WHEN `12 February 2020`>'' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `12 February 2020`='', `12 February 2020`)
               END rn
FROM cte1
)
SELECT id,
       NAMA_LENGKAP,
       MAX(`02 February 2020`),
       MAX(`07 February 2020`),
       MAX(`10 February 2020`),
       MAX(`11 February 2020`),
       MAX(`12 February 2020`)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, NAMA_LENGKAP, rn;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=662071285e765f0e46c0613577c88576).

---

I have demonstrated HOW to do this. But you will have to write the generation of the corresponding query text by yourself.

Comment: ok thanks i will study, understand and try it.  Once again, thank you very much for responding

Comment: I tried writing `WITH` in mysql but the error is `unrecognized type statement (near with)`. i used 10.2.31-MariaDB

Comment: @yuaneko Maybe your MySQL version is too ancient (below 8.0)? If so remove CTEs and put their code into FROM clause (i.e. replace `WITH cte AS (cte code) SELECT ... FROM cte ...` with `SELECT ... FROM (cte code) AS cte ...` - and alter aliases to achieve their uniqueness over the whole query).

Comment: *i used 10.2.31-MariaDB* This verson supports CTEs (see [Common Table Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/) - "Common table expressions were introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1."). And the message "unrecognized type statement (near with)" is NOT MariaDB message. I think this is your connector library issue - update it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. at the moment my problem is solved but that still needs to be checked again. maybe you have a better suggestion than the store procedure that I made in Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=67875715f95e8735992b02a17c67307e

Comment: @yuaneko 1) In my opinion SP is safe solution. 2) Do not declare the same cursor - simply reopen it (declare ... ; open ... ; fetch ... ; close ... ; open ... ; fetch ... ; ...). New continue handler and variable are excess too. Moreover, you may collect all 3 parts in one LOOP, and reopening won't be needed. 3) SELECT DISTINCT in cursor is more safe then GROUP BY.